Is 1 staked SOL always worth at least 1 SOL
The Solana native staking program (https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/tree/master/sdk/program) currently doesn't support slashing or otherwise reducing the value of a validator's stake. That means that if 1000 SOL is staked to a validator, in the worst case, that staked position will always be worth at least 1000 SOL. It may not grow in value, be it cannot shrink.
Is it fair to build on top of the native staking program while making a technical assumption such as:
1_staked_sol >= 1_sol
Is it fair to say that this will always be the case, and if not, what could change and when?

This is correct, but keep in mind that slashing will be implemented at some point in the next couple of years.
